# Unable to show up Subtitles in Videojs player

Tags: html, subtitle

Unable to show up subtitles in the video, i have used the following track element as shown in the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 .vjs-default-skin { color: #fdfdfd; }
 .vjs-default-skin .vjs-play-progress,
 .vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-level { background-color: #1880b8 }
 .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar { font-size: 100% }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-    centered" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{"controls": true,    "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }'>
<source src="Game.of.Thrones.S05E10.HDTV.x264-KILLERS.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<track label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en"         src="http://mcpocketeditionforapt.altervista.org/sub.vtt"></track>

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably a CORS issue. What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: it is showing CORS error , and unable to find any solution for CORS @misterben

Answer (score 2):

There are two ays to resolve this.

1. Configure the server hosting the captions to send CORS headers (documented at [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/) and on various questions on SO) *and* add a `crossdomain` attribute to the `video` element (`<video crossdomain id="MY_VIDEO_1" …`).
2. Host the captions on the same domain as your page so CORS headers are not needed.